# Retrieving Images Off Rails API That Used Paperclip and S3 to Handle Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm working on a project that uses a Rails API for the backend and has a separate front end calling on that API. This is the first project where I've had to store images on the API and after days of research on best practices, I'm now more confused than I was going into it. Basically, I use Paperclip and S3 to handle uploading images onto the API, but I've hit a roadblock now that I'm trying to call on the API to retrieve those images. I'm very new to handling images this way and don't know if I should somehow generate a url and store that in the database to call on for retrieving and displaying the images on the front end, or if there is a way to take the multiple parts of the image that Paperclip creates and generate the image from those? The API successfully calls the rest of the data like my object names and bios, I just can't figure out the proper way to store the images so I can easily retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using paperclip to upload images to amazon s3 then the object that the attatchment is associated with should have a method that is the name of whatever you set the item name as when you generated your paperclip migrations.

For example if when you generated the migration using... 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#migrations

```
rails generate paperclip user avatar
```

then this will give you the method on `User` called `.avatar` and this will in turn give you a method called `.url` that you can call on avatar.

i.e.

```
User.avatar.url
```

will give you the url to the location where the image is stored on S3